# What does it mean by 'tongue between someone's teeth'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> "Gallopin' Gorgons, that reminds me," said Hagird, ....... he pulled an owl-a real, live, rather ruffled-looking owl-a long quill, and a roll of parchment. **With his tongue between his teeth** he scribbled a note that Harry could read upside down : ........

I don't understand the meaning of 'tongue between his teeth' here.
Is it like someone's biting his/her tongue when they are nervous?
But it's not the case here, I guess...

Comment: Your assumption is absolutely correct. Well done! It simply means that the character placed his tongue between his teeth while writing. It has no deep symbolic meaning. The phrase describes what the character is doing, and nothing more.

Comment: @P.E.Dant thanks! so it has nothing to do with someone's 'nervous', am I right?

Comment: I think not, but I have not read the entire work, so I cannot speak with authority.

Comment: It has nothing to do with nervousness. It is how someone is described when digging in to do a job assiduously. It's a caricature, though, not something you normally see in real life, especially during vigorous activity given the danger the tongue would be exposed to. Usually this posture is reserved for cartoonish descriptions such as would appear in comic strips or the works of J. K. Rowland.